# How to delete files or directory remotely in Bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket

If you exceed the 2GB limit, how do you delete directories or files since you cannot commit? The repository is now in read-only mode. I accidentally exceeded the limit due to an error in the .gitignore and cannot force a commit to fix it. I don't want to delete the repository and start over because it's a 1GB-sized project and took several hours to push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do anything about this on your own. You will have to contact [Technical Support](https://support.bitbucket.org/) directly and get them to help you.

[image]